# excel vba regex pattern exact string match

Tags: regex, vba, excel, string-matching

Hi I'm trying to fix my code to do the following (with some context)

There are 2 columns in excel: column P and column S. Both columns are thousands and thousands of rows long.

Column P are all multi-lined text strings (descriptions of products)
Column S are all multi-lined text strings (comments of products)

I need to write a vba function that will look into the cell in column P and return the exact string match if there is a match pertaining to the values in column S.

Example: 
[image]

Using regular expressions I have been able to do this comparing one row at a time (P3 to S3) using the code below:

```
Public Function RxMatch( _
 ByVal SourceString As String, _
 ByVal Pattern As String, _
 Seperator As String, _
 Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, _
 Optional ByVal MultiLine As Boolean = True) As Variant

Dim arrWords() As String
arrWords = Split(SourceString, separator)

 Dim oMatches As MatchCollection
 For Each word In arrWords
 With New RegExp
    .MultiLine = MultiLine
    .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    .Global = False
    .Pattern = Pattern
    Set oMatches = .Execute(SourceString)
    If oMatches.Count > 0 Then
        RxMatch = oMatches(0).Value
    Else
        RxMatch = "No match"
    End If
 End With
 Next word

 End Function
```

however instead of comparing P3 to S3 for a match I need to compare P3 to all of column S to see if any of the descriptions have a match. Is there a way to update this code that I provided so that it matches off of the entire column S instead of cell to cell?

Comment: With as many entries as you have, you're probably going to have trouble finding an efficient way to do this. A nested `foreach` loop is the most obvious approach, but it will be slow.

Comment: Using arrays will be much quicker.

Comment: arrays and Instr? Sorry, I can't enlarge image at present to view data properly.

Comment: Does VLOOKUP help you? In my experience, it is faster than VBA.

Comment: Are you just checking to see if any of the substrings in column S are contained in the longer strings in column P? Your image is very small and hard to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are careful about any hidden characters, line breaks etc then you should be able to use arrays and Instr function.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindMatches()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, j As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        arr = .Range("P1:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                If InStr(arr(i, 1), arr(j, 4)) > 0 Then arr(i, 5) = arr(i, 5) & "," & arr(j, 4)
            Next j
        Next i
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(arr(i, 5), ",", vbNullString, 1)
        Next i
        .Range("P1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Dataset with output in column T:**

[image: Dataset]

Comment: Any feedback at all?